# Define a numbered, referenceable environment

Tags: amsmath, environments, cleveref, tikz-cd

In the document that I am writing, I regularly need to draw commutative diagrams using tikz-cd (see MWE).
I'd like to define a custom `diagram` environment which has the following properties:

1. no boilerplate code: only the tikz-cd commands are present within the environment
2. centered
3. has its own counter
4. referenceable with reference name `Diagram ??`

My best attempt is to wrap `equation` and `tikzcd` into one environment, but this does not solve the cross-referencing and has weird indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

% custom environment
\newenvironment{diagram}{%
    \begin{equation}\begin{tikzcd}%
    }{%
    \end{tikzcd}\end{equation}%
    }

\begin{document}
A numbered equation-diagram:
\begin{equation}
    \label{dia:equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \ar[r] & B
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
However, the reference is an equation: \cref{dia:equation}

\begin{diagram}
    \label{dia:diagram-env}
    A \ar[r] & B
\end{diagram}
Note the weird indentation of \cref{dia:diagram-env} at the start of this line and that (obviously) the reference still mentions an equation and the counter is (obviously) still bounded to other equations. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think your code is inserting `label` inside `tikzcd`. What you want is outer of it but inside `equation`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the value of `equation` and replace it by the current value of `diagram`. Using `\crefalias` is the key.

I defined `diagram` with an optional argument for options to `tikz-cd`: they're often needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

% custom environment
\newcounter{diagram}
\crefname{diagram}{Diagram}{Diagrams}
\newcounter{savedequation}
\newenvironment{diagram}[1][]
 {%
  \setcounter{savedequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{diagram}}%
  \crefalias{equation}{diagram}%
  \begin{equation}\begin{tikzcd}[#1]%
 }
 {%
  \end{tikzcd}\end{equation}%
  \setcounter{diagram}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{savedequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend % <-- no space after the diagram environment
 }

\begin{document}
A numbered diagram:
\begin{diagram}
    \label{dia:equation}
        A \ar[r] & B
\end{diagram}
and the reference is a to a diagram: \cref{dia:equation}
\begin{diagram}
    \label{dia:diagram-env}
    A \ar[r] & B
\end{diagram}
There is no weird indentation of \cref{dia:diagram-env} at the start 
of this line and the reference mentions ``Diagram''.
Now we have a regular equation
\begin{equation}\label{try}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
How will the reader distinguish between \cref{try} and \cref{dia:equation}?

\end{document}
```

However, as you see, you have a problem of duplicate numbers, if you plan to have also numbered equations.

[image]

For `hyperref`:

```
\newenvironment{diagram}[1][]
 {%
  \setcounter{savedequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{diagram}}%
  \renewcommand{\theHequation}{diagram\theequation}% <--- keep hyperref happy
  \crefalias{equation}{diagram}%
  \begin{equation}\begin{tikzcd}[#1]%
 }
 {%
  \end{tikzcd}\end{equation}%
  \setcounter{diagram}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{savedequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend % <-- no space after the diagram environment
 }
```

Comment: You are right about the possible confusion! `crefalias` is indeed key and that's what I ended up using.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things to do here. First you want a counter, so you'll need to define this with `\newcounter`:

```
\newcounter{diagram}
```

We'll come back to this after we figure out the formatting.

Your extra space on the first line is a consequence of how the `equation` environment manages ignoring spaces after `\end{equation}`—by setting `\@ignoretrue` which informs LaTeX to do `\ignorespaces` when we finish the environment. However, that setting is lost because of the use of `\begin` and `\end` to start and end the equation since those wrap everything in a group and we lose the value of `\@ignoretrue` when `\end{diagram}` is called.

**Possibly boring aside**: If we used `\begin{center}`...`\end{center}` around the `tikzcd` environment, we don't get that extra space. Digging into what's happening (the `center` environment is a variation of the `trivlist` environment), the magic is because `equation` (and `displaymath` and `\[`...`\]`) is a relatively thin wrapper around `$$`...`$$`¹. **end of aside**

Since `equation` gives you most of what you want, other than numbering, we can use a variation of it to produce your centering: We'll need to have `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` surrounding this to be able to set `\@ignoretrue`:

```latex
\newenvironment{diagram}{%
    $$\refstepcounter{diagram}
      \begin{tikzcd}
    }{%
    \end{tikzcd}
    \eqno\hbox{\normalfont\normalcolor (\thediagram)}$$\@ignoretrue
    }
```

`\refstepcounter` advances the `diagram` counter we defined earlier, and causes any `\label` inside the `diagram` environment to refer to the newly set value for the counter. `\eqno` is a TeX primitive that lets us put the equation number to the side. I've put all the formatting for the diagram number directly into the declaration of the `diagram` environment, but if you were creating this for more general use, you might want to break that into a separate command to make it easier for users to customize the appearance.

---

1. Question for the LaTeX 3 core team: Shouldn't `\begin{equation}` include the following like unnumbered display math does?

```
\ifvmode
    \nointerlineskip
    \makebox[.6\linewidth]{}%
\fi
```

Comment: You can use `\crefname{diagram}{diagram}{diagrams}
\Crefname{diagram}{Diagram}{Diagrams}` to have the correct `\cref{}` tagging too...

Comment: This works perfectly and was very insightful! I choose the other answer because I could understand the code more easily, but thank you nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your desired typeset result is bu the following may help you.

```
% envprob.tex  SE 591990
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%\makeatletter
%\newcommand{\p@diagctr}{\thediagctr}
\newcounter{diagctr}
\newenvironment{diagram}{%
  \centering
  \refstepcounter{diagctr}%
  Diagram \arabic{diagctr}
  \[
  \begin{tikzcd}}
  {\end{tikzcd}\]\par}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

A numbered equation-diagram:
\begin{equation}
    \label{dia:equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \ar[r] & B
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
However, the reference is an equation: \cref{dia:equation}

\begin{diagram}
    A \ar[r] & B
    \label{dia:diagram-env}
\end{diagram}

\begin{diagram}
    A \ar[r] & B
    \label{dia:diagram-second}
\end{diagram}

Note that this reference \verb!\ref{dia:diagram-second}!  
Diagram \ref{dia:diagram-second} is to the diagram number.

\end{document}
```

[image]